# TCP or UDP request doesn't come to application

Tags: windows, sockets, tcp, configuration, udp

Preamble.

I have some specific application (called LinkBit PacketCraft) for network signaling testing. Scripts of this App have a specific procedure for opening a socket for requests receiving (in my case it is SIP over UDP and HTTP requests) that consist of two blocks: "TCP/IP Control.Open Request" and "TCP/IP Control.Open Confirm" with such parameters as IP(v4/v6), port and protocol (TCP/UDP). I don't know what they exactly do, but as a result after this procedure I can receive requests on specified ip/port.

The Problem.

It worked well until our IT engineers re-installed OS (Windows Server 2008 R2). Don't ask me why, just should be. After re-installation I have one server where it works as well and one server where it doesn't work. My script show me that socket opened successfully, I do see incoming requests (SIP over UDP and HTTP) in the WireShark on this machine, but application doesn't receive them.

I have completely the same script and the same version of application on another server where it works.

Our IT-service can't find any difference between servers configuration, but I don't believe them.

Who may knows which setting or configuration may be responsible for requests delivery to application?

P.S. Just one remark. If I send SIP HTTP request in my script, the application can receive requests and responses to the same socket was used for sending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Firewall. I received all requests when I disabled it.